# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'laneId' of undefined for add card

Tags: reactjs, trello

After adding card and add data into table i want to update cards detail with original card id which return from table. For this i have used eventBusHandle like this :

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Board from "react-trello";


const TaskBoard = (props) =>{
const [eventBus, setEventBus] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
        if (card.length !== 0) {
            eventBus.publish({type: 'ADD_CARD', laneId:card.column_id, cards: {id: card.id, title: card.title, label: "1 sec", description: card.description}});
        }
    }, [card.length]);

return(
        <Board
        id="board1"
        components={components}
        style={{
            background: '#F1F2F4'
        }}
        data={boardData}
        draggable
        handleLaneDragStart={handleLaneDragStart}
        handleLaneDragEnd={handleLaneDragEnd}
        canAddLanes
        onLaneAdd={onLaneAdd}
        onLaneDelete={onLaneDelete}
        handleDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
        onCardDelete={onCardDelete}
        onCardAdd={onCardAdd}
        editable
        eventBusHandle={setEventBus}
        />
    );

}
```

I need to update real card id for delete or move other place.

[image]

Comment: Where does `publish()` come from?

Comment: hi @yudhiesh, react-trello provide .publish() hook to add/update/delete card.. you can check it here - https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is no way to know where the card information comes from. The publish method will update the board information with "defined" information. So you need to have a defined card before using the method.

Also, the setEventBus happens after the board is created (mounted). If you are trying to update the board using publish() before the setEventBus happens, it will not work.

So I would use this code to update the card:

```
const onCardAddHandler = (card, laneId) => {
  eventBus.publish({
    type: 'UPDATE_CARD', //use this type instead of ADD_CARD
    laneId:laneId,
    card: {
      id: card.id,
      title: card.title,
      label: "1 sec",
      description: card.description
    }
  });
}
```

Then in your Board, replace your onCardAdd like this:

```
<Board
  id="board1"
  components={components}
  style={{ background: '#F1F2F4' }}
  data={boardData}
  draggable
  handleLaneDragStart={handleLaneDragStart}
  handleLaneDragEnd={handleLaneDragEnd}
  canAddLanes
  onLaneAdd={onLaneAdd}
  onLaneDelete={onLaneDelete}
  handleDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
  onCardDelete={onCardDelete}
  onCardAdd={onCardAddHandler}. //here I collect de card information
  editable
  eventBusHandle={setEventBus}
/>
```